# Trigger to create policy on Oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers, policy, create-table

I have two schemas:

> my_user sec_admin

`sec_admin` has the right the create policies on any table of `my_user`.
We have created a procedure inside of a package `my_package.my_proc()` that generates and executes all the create policy statements.

So far so good, everything has been working fine. 
Now, we've realized that when `my_user` drops a table (and recreates it), the attached policy automatically gets dropped. A solution is to re-use manually `my_package.my_proc()` to re-generate the policy. But the fact is, the drop and create table statements are created by SAS developers who don't have access to Oracle SQL Developer. Therefore, the call to `my_package.my_proc()` should be automatized, by using a trigger

so we've created a simple trigger on `my_user`:

```
create or replace
TRIGGER test_trig
AFTER CREATE
ON SCHEMA

DECLARE
--oper ddl_log.operation%TYPE;
v_object_type varchar2(100);
BEGIN

  SELECT  ora_dict_obj_type
  into v_object_type
  FROM DUAL;
  If upper(v_object_type)='TABLE' then 
      SEC_ADMIN.my_package.my_proc();
  end if;
END test_trig;
```

It seems that when we create a table, the first time the trigger partially works. When we create a second table, the trigger seems to work, but `PF_OWNER` inside of `dba_policies` is `my_user` instead of `SEC_ADMIN`. Therefore my policy is not working anymore.

It seems that I have to run the procedure `SEC_ADMIN.my_package.my_proc()` as `SEC_ADMIN` as part of a solution but I don't know how.

I'm also open to alternative solutions if you have any. It seems like the problem is that whenever a table is dropped, the attached policy is dropped with it...

Thanks for your help

Comment: Should this be closed as a duplicate of [your later question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24960225/266304), or does that not fully answer what you're doing here? (It seems like it does but not 100% sure). You might also want to look into `authid` but it soudns like what you have ought to work by default; and having the trigger in a different schema means that `my_user` can't drop it themselves, of course.

Comment: I will test that when my DBA gives me the rights you suggested. In the meantime, if you have an alternative solution I'd love to read it!

Comment: Wasn't my suggestion, but I upvoted it before I saw this one... How is `SEC_ADMIN.my_package.my_proc()` defined? Does it specify `authid`?

Comment: it doesn't specify authid. It's just a procedure inside of a package, none defined with Authid. Should I add it?
I tried implementing the trigger on sec_admin. It is working, but the PF_OWNER is still my_user. Therefore the policy doesn't work. It's driving me crazy

Comment: okay, I added the statement: function_schema => 'SEC_ADMIN' and it works! Now my last problem is that the procedure only fully terminates once out of two times......... any idea?

Comment: Not off-hand, but not quite sure what you mean. Does it error? Does it seem to run but not create the policy? Are you running it again for the same table?

Comment: I actually narrowed the problem... still haven't found a solution. Will ask a new question to make it clearer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58027/discussion-between-user3019499-and-alex-poole).