# Create trigger on Oracle from a user that listens to events for another user

Tags: oracle, triggers, schema

I have two Oracle schemas A & B.

Can I create a trigger in schema A that will listen to Create Tables on Schema B?
If yes, which grants do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. The user a needs to have `CREATE ANY TRIGGER`:

As DBA:

```
CREATE USER a IDENTIFIED BY a;
GRANT CREATE SESSION, CREATE ANY TRIGGER TO a;

CREATE USER b IDENTIFIED BY b;
GRANT CREATE SESSION TO b;
```

As a:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER a.create_trigger
  BEFORE CREATE ON b.SCHEMA
BEGIN
  raise_application_error(num => -20000,  msg=> 'create_trigger vetoes');
END;
/
```

As b:

```
CREATE TABLE t(i INT);
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-20000: create_trigger vetoes
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

You'll have to fine-tune this trigger, it will fire not only for `CREATE TABLE` but for all `CREATE` statements...

Comment: Thanks! Question: if you use this trigger to create policies, should this be BEFORE CREATE or AFTER CREATE? I believe After but I just want to confirm

Comment: @user3019499 - if you wanted to block tables being created then `BEFORE`; but for your scenario creating a policy then `AFTER`, yes.